# Buggy Scrollbar Behavior

Tags: html, css, scroll, flexbox, scrollbar

I'm trying to implement a scroll-able content layout and I managed to do it, however the scrollbar is displaying strange behavior - sometimes it cannot get clicked, sometimes the arrows do not move it, sometimes only 1 arrow can move it even though there is space to be scrolled in either direction, etc..

```css
.content-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  flex-grow: 1;
  /* for Firefox */
  min-height: 0;
}

.tsp-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="tsp-content">
    <div class="MuiPaper-root MuiCard-root MuiPaper-outlined MuiPaper-rounded">
      <div class="MuiCardContent-root">
        <p>Lorem -&gt; Ipsum (0328)</p>
      </div>
      <div class="MuiCardActions-root tsp-card-buttons MuiCardActions-spacing">
        <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-outlined MuiButton-outlinedSecondary MuiButton-outlinedSizeSmall MuiButton-sizeSmall" tabindex="0" type="button"><span class="MuiButton-label">LoremIpsum</span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="MuiPaper-root MuiCard-root MuiPaper-outlined MuiPaper-rounded">
      <div class="MuiCardContent-root">
        <p>Lorem -&gt; Ipsum (0328)</p>
      </div>
      <div class="MuiCardActions-root tsp-card-buttons MuiCardActions-spacing">
        <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-outlined MuiButton-outlinedSecondary MuiButton-outlinedSizeSmall MuiButton-sizeSmall" tabindex="0" type="button"><span class="MuiButton-label">LoremIpsum</span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="MuiPaper-root MuiCard-root MuiPaper-outlined MuiPaper-rounded">
      <div class="MuiCardContent-root">
        <p>Lorem -&gt; Ipsum (0328)</p>
      </div>
      <div class="MuiCardActions-root transportation-card-buttons MuiCardActions-spacing">
        <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-outlined MuiButton-outlinedSecondary MuiButton-outlinedSizeSmall MuiButton-sizeSmall" tabindex="0" type="button"><span class="MuiButton-label">LoremIpsum</span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="MuiPaper-root MuiCard-root MuiPaper-outlined MuiPaper-rounded">
      <div class="MuiCardContent-root">
        <p>Lorem -&gt; Ipsum (0328)</p>
      </div>
      <div class="MuiCardActions-root tsp-card-buttons MuiCardActions-spacing">
        <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-outlined MuiButton-outlinedSecondary MuiButton-outlinedSizeSmall MuiButton-sizeSmall" tabindex="0" type="button"><span class="MuiButton-label">LoremIpsum</span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="MuiPaper-root MuiCard-root MuiPaper-outlined MuiPaper-rounded">
      <div class="MuiCardContent-root">
        <p>Lorem -&gt; Ipsum (0328)</p>
      </div>
      <div class="MuiCardActions-root tsp-card-buttons MuiCardActions-spacing">
        <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-outlined MuiButton-outlinedSecondary MuiButton-outlinedSizeSmall MuiButton-sizeSmall" tabindex="0" type="button"><span class="MuiButton-label">LoremIpsum</span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="MuiPaper-root MuiCard-root MuiPaper-outlined MuiPaper-rounded">
      <div class="MuiCardContent-root">
        <p>Lorem -&gt; Ipsum (0328)</p>
      </div>
      <div class="MuiCardActions-root tsp-card-buttons MuiCardActions-spacing">
        <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-outlined MuiButton-outlinedSecondary MuiButton-outlinedSizeSmall MuiButton-sizeSmall" tabindex="0" type="button"><span class="MuiButton-label">LoremIpsum</span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="MuiPaper-root MuiCard-root MuiPaper-outlined MuiPaper-rounded">
      <div class="MuiCardContent-root">
        <p>Lorem -&gt; Ipsum (0328)</p>
      </div>
      <div class="MuiCardActions-root tsp-card-buttons MuiCardActions-spacing">
        <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-outlined MuiButton-outlinedSecondary MuiButton-outlinedSizeSmall MuiButton-sizeSmall" tabindex="0" type="button"><span class="MuiButton-label">LoremIpsum</span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="MuiPaper-root MuiCard-root MuiPaper-outlined MuiPaper-rounded">
      <div class="MuiCardContent-root">
        <p>Lorem -&gt; Ipsum (0328)</p>
      </div>
      <div class="MuiCardActions-root tsp-card-buttons MuiCardActions-spacing">
        <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-outlined MuiButton-outlinedSecondary MuiButton-outlinedSizeSmall MuiButton-sizeSmall" tabindex="0" type="button"><span class="MuiButton-label">LoremIpsum</span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="MuiPaper-root MuiCard-root MuiPaper-outlined MuiPaper-rounded">
      <div class="MuiCardContent-root">
        <p>Lorem -&gt; Ipsum (0328)</p>
      </div>
      <div class="MuiCardActions-root tsp-card-buttons MuiCardActions-spacing">
        <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-outlined MuiButton-outlinedSecondary MuiButton-outlinedSizeSmall MuiButton-sizeSmall" tabindex="0" type="button"><span class="MuiButton-label">LoremIpsum</span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="MuiPaper-root MuiCard-root MuiPaper-outlined MuiPaper-rounded">
      <div class="MuiCardContent-root">
        <p>Lorem -&gt; Ipsum (0328)</p>
      </div>
      <div class="MuiCardActions-root tsp-card-buttons MuiCardActions-spacing">
        <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-outlined MuiButton-outlinedSecondary MuiButton-outlinedSizeSmall MuiButton-sizeSmall" tabindex="0" type="button"><span class="MuiButton-label">LoremIpsum</span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the codepen: https://codepen.io/JustM/pen/PoqGNGP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is that the `<img class="path"/>` is on the top of the scrollable content, so that's why it won't scroll.

I added `z-index: 0;` to `.path` and `z-index:1;` to `.content-wrapper` and it worked.

you can check it here
https://codepen.io/remyjouni/pen/JjdRKxb

I highly recommend any kind of background shapes to be added in CSS as a background.

Comment: that fixed it, thanks! Do you know why the z-index caused the issue? How I understand it - is that the scrollbar belongs to the content-wrapper div which is a separate element altogether.. Why did it interact with the img in that way?

Comment: `z-index` didn't cause the issue. how the scrolling work is that the web browser will try to scroll the content ur mouse cursor is currently on. and most of the time your cursor was above the image, try to put your mouse to the left side of the screen and scroll will work because you are now above the scrollable content.
my solution was a hack for an unnecessary problem. as I told you to try to use CSS for an image background like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp)